# show pdf file in a icefaces modalpopup

Tags: pdf, icefaces, modalpopup

Is it possible to show a pdf file in modalpopup with icefaces. Tried this but does not seem to work. Am new to icefaces too.

```
                        <ice:panelPopup autoCentre="true" visible="#{popup.visible}" modal="true">
                            <f:facet name="header"/>
                            <f:facet name="body">

                               <OBJECT DATA="/ICEfacesDevelopersGuide.pdf" TYPE="application/pdf" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" />
                                <ice:commandButton value="Close" action="#{popup.close}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </ice:panelPopup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it the old way opening it on a new window or tab using output link and target attribute.